# regex - How to make optional the end of the line

Tags: python, regex, url, expression

I'm programming a URL parser to get some values in order to do some stats.
For example I want to parse only the username:

```
uSSer=andoni&password=contra
```

(I only want to get the value of uSSer or some likely field from an url) and im using this regexp:

```
.*?[u,U][s,S][e,E][r,R].*?=(.*)&
```

It works if the parameter uSSer is before the & token on the URL, but if it is the last field from a URL? Like this:

```
parameter1=foo&password=contra&uSSer=andoni
```

Comment: You have a `.*?` between `us` and `er`. Do you intend for this match `us=foo&er=bar`? Please be more specific about your requirements.

Comment: Use the [URL parser](http://devdocs.io/python/library/urllib.parse#urllib.parse.urlparse)

Comment: That's [how](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urlparse.py#l390) Python solves it.This is a good example of: "regex now I have two problems".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks quite funny to me. I removed the `.*?` and the `,`.

```
(^|&)[uU][sS][sS][eE][rR]=([^&]*)
```

It begins with either `&` or nothing. And the user is as long as no ampersand characters are found.

You can test it here:
http://regex101.com/r/wI5oX2/1

Answer (score 0):

Put in the class whatever you want to use for a delimiter.
This only works if Python supports lookbehinds.
If you intend case insensitive, put a `(?i)` at the head of the regex.
Or, if Python doesn't support inline modifiers, put it as a function option.
If it doesn't support that, use `[aA]` like you are doing it.

```
 # (?<=[&/?\r\n])uSSer=([^&/?\r\n]+)

 (?<= [&/?\r\n] )
 uSSer=
 ( [^&/?\r\n]+ )       # (1)
```